# How to find the last occurrence of a char in a string?

Tags: string, rust

I want to find the index of the last forward slash `/` in a string. For example, I have the string `/test1/test2/test3` and I want to find the location of the slash before `test3`. How can I achieve this?

In Python, I would use `rfind` but I can't find anything like that in Rust.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to use [`std::str::rfind`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.str.html#method.rfind). Note that it returns an `Option<usize>`, so you will need to account for that when checking its result:

```
fn main() {
    let s = "/test1/test2/test3";
    let pos = s.rfind('/');

    println!("{:?}", pos); // prints "Some(12)"
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[@ljedrz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1870153/ljedrz)'s solution will not give you the correct result if your string contains non-ASCII characters.

Here is a slower solution but it will always give you correct answer:

```rust
let s = "/test1/test2/test3";
let pos = s.chars().count() - s.chars().rev().position(|c| c == '/').unwrap() - 1;
```

Or you can use this as a function:

```rust
fn rfind_utf8(s: &str, chr: char) -> Option<usize> {
    if let Some(rev_pos) = s.chars().rev().position(|c| c == chr) {
        Some(s.chars().count() - rev_pos - 1)
    } else {
        None
    }
}
```

Comment: The result obtained from `rfind` is correct, it will just return the character's _byte position_ in the string rather than its position as a Unicode scalar value.